# In a Flutter ListView, how do I know the index number of the first and last items in view?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

Given a ListView, which is scrolled by some offset, how do I know the index number of the first and last items currently in view?

I have tried this:

```
class MySliverChildBuilderDelegate extends SliverChildBuilderDelegate {
  MySliverChildBuilderDelegate(IndexedWidgetBuilder builder, {int childCount})
      : super(builder, childCount: childCount);

  @override
  void didFinishLayout(int firstIndex, int lastIndex) {
    print("firstIndex = $firstIndex / lastIndex = $lastIndex");
  }
}
```

And then:

```
SliverChildBuilderDelegate childrenDelegate =
    MySliverChildBuilderDelegate(itemBuilder, childCount: childCount);

ListView.custom(
    controller: _controller,
    childrenDelegate: childrenDelegate));
```

But those firstIndex and lastIndex are not actually what I though they were...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2020, I guess the answer to this question would be to use a `ScrollablePositionedList` (https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) instead of a `ListView`.

Then you can monitor which items are visible on screen:

```
itemPositionsListener.positions.addListener((positions) => ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

This information is not available.

The most you can get is the indexes of what has been laid out by `RenderSliverList` (a lower layer of `ListView`).

Which is the equivalent of what's visible + a potential extra around it.

Comment: Do you know what are, exactly, firstIndex and lastIndex in the didFinishLayout method?

Comment: These are the indexes of what has been rendered on screen. It is close to what's visible but may contain a few extra before/after what's actually visible.

Comment: Why does it need to render widgets which are not visible? Even internally, it doesn't know when to start/end? And if it doesnt know at all, how can it choose a  firstIndex and lastIndex to start with, even if they have some extra before/after?

Comment: I don't know the details, sorry. You can take a peek at `RenderSliverList` code, which contains all that logic.